# How to prove both sides of  this equality - sets (discrete mathematics)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

```
A = A U '('A U B)
```

I know how to prove A U '('A U B)  but how do I prove the other side? Is this correct? Is it ok just to add 'B?

```
A /* identity laws */
A U Ø /*domination laws */
A U (Ø ∩ 'B) /* distributive laws */
(A U Ø) ∩ ( A U 'B) /*identity laws */
A ∩ ( A U 'B) /* distributive laws */
(A ∩ A) U (A ∩ 'B) /*idempotent laws */
A U (A ∩ 'B) /*de morgan's laws */
A U '('A U B)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have that $A = A \cup X$ for some set $X$.  You'd hope that $X \subseteq A$ so RHS is not bigger than LHS.

$(A' \cup B)' = A \cap B' \subseteq A$ so we're good.